# how to run training on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, training-data

I am trying to run a training on my GPU with Cuda.
But when I start the training I receive this error: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'keras.engine.training.Model'>

Here's the code:`

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import cls_data_generator
import evaluation_metrics
import keras_model
import parameter
import utils
import time
from IPython import embed
plot.switch_backend('agg')
#------------------------------------- CUDA ----------------------------------------------
from numba import jit, cuda
from numba import NumbaDeprecationWarning, NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=NumbaDeprecationWarning)
warnings.simplefilter('ignore', category=NumbaPendingDeprecationWarning)
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

...

```
@cuda.jit(nopython=True)
def training(nb_epoch,model,data_gen_train,data_gen_test,params,tr_loss,val_loss,sed_loss,                               doa_loss,sed_gt,doa_gt,epoch_metric_loss,unique_name,patience_cnt,conf_mat,best_conf_mat,best_metric):
    for epoch_cnt in range(nb_epoch):
        start = time.time()
        hist = model.fit_generator(
            generator=data_gen_train.generate(),
            steps_per_epoch=2 if params['quick_test'] else data_gen_train.get_total_batches_in_data(),
            validation_data=data_gen_test.generate(),
            validation_steps=2 if params['quick_test'] else data_gen_test.get_total_batches_in_data(),
            epochs=1,
            verbose=0
        )
        tr_loss[epoch_cnt] = hist.history.get('loss')[-1]
        val_loss[epoch_cnt] = hist.history.get('val_loss')[-1]

        pred = model.predict_generator(
            generator=data_gen_test.generate(),
            steps=2 if params['quick_test'] else data_gen_test.get_total_batches_in_data(),
            verbose=2
        )
        if params['mode'] == 'regr':
            sed_pred = evaluation_metrics.reshape_3Dto2D(pred[0]) > 0.5
            doa_pred = evaluation_metrics.reshape_3Dto2D(pred[1])

            sed_loss[epoch_cnt, :] = evaluation_metrics.compute_sed_scores(sed_pred, sed_gt, data_gen_test.nb_frames_1s())
            if params['azi_only']:
                doa_loss[epoch_cnt, :], conf_mat = evaluation_metrics.compute_doa_scores_regr_xy(doa_pred, doa_gt,
                                                                                                 sed_pred, sed_gt)
            else:
                doa_loss[epoch_cnt, :], conf_mat = evaluation_metrics.compute_doa_scores_regr_xyz(doa_pred, doa_gt,
                                                                                                  sed_pred, sed_gt)

            epoch_metric_loss[epoch_cnt] = np.mean([
                sed_loss[epoch_cnt, 0],
                1-sed_loss[epoch_cnt, 1],
                2*np.arcsin(doa_loss[epoch_cnt, 1]/2.0)/np.pi,
                1 - (doa_loss[epoch_cnt, 5] / float(doa_gt.shape[0]))]
            )
        plot_functions(unique_name, tr_loss, val_loss, sed_loss, doa_loss, epoch_metric_loss)

        patience_cnt += 1
        if epoch_metric_loss[epoch_cnt] < best_metric:
            best_metric = epoch_metric_loss[epoch_cnt]
            best_conf_mat = conf_mat
            best_epoch = epoch_cnt
            model.save('{}_model.h5'.format(unique_name))
            patience_cnt = 0

        print(
            'epoch_cnt: %d, time: %.2fs, tr_loss: %.2f, val_loss: %.2f, '
            'F1_overall: %.2f, ER_overall: %.2f, '
            'doa_error_gt: %.2f, doa_error_pred: %.2f, good_pks_ratio:%.2f, '
            'error_metric: %.2f, best_error_metric: %.2f, best_epoch : %d' %
            (
                epoch_cnt, time.time() - start, tr_loss[epoch_cnt], val_loss[epoch_cnt],
                sed_loss[epoch_cnt, 1], sed_loss[epoch_cnt, 0],
                doa_loss[epoch_cnt, 1], doa_loss[epoch_cnt, 2], doa_loss[epoch_cnt, 5] / float(sed_gt.shape[0]),
                epoch_metric_loss[epoch_cnt], best_metric, best_epoch
            )
        )
        if patience_cnt > params['patience']:
            break
```

I think that the problem is when I give 'model' as argument to function 'training'.
model is a keras model defined in 'keras_model.py'.
But I can't fix this problem.. Anyone can help me?

P.S. I have to use python 3.7, tensorflow 1.14.0, keras 2.2.4., numpy=1.16.4

I want do adapt this code to run on GPU with Cuda, but I can't understand how to do.
I added Numba and jit stuff.

Comment: Keras already has GPU support from TensorFlow, I don't think mixing numba into it is going to work.

Comment: Can you help me? I can't understand how to run on GPU

Comment: I already said, why are you not just using tensorflow GPU support? What problem are you having?

Comment: So, I don't need to change the code? If the  GPU is avaiable, will tensorflow run the training on the GPU?

Comment: I don't need to add Numba?

Comment: There is no need for Numba, as I said already, TensorFlow has GPU support, it just needs to be setup correctly.

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to install tensorflow with GPU support in your system by following mentioned Hardware and Software requirements.

Answer (score 0):

As per the numba [deprecation recommendation](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/drive/1CMwX6KzRukzL28xUH0xnrdxpBbHdECft#scrollTo=_9EviFJHpliE) the code which does not compile with the `@cuda.jit(nopython=True)` will run faster without this decorator.

Instead , you can pass your pandas dataframe directly to the vectorize operation.

```
import pandas as pd 
import dask.dataframe as dd 
from dask.multiprocessing import get 
data = <your_pandas_dataframe>
ddata = dd.from_pandas(data, npartitions=30)

def myfunc(x,y,z, ...): return <whatever>

res = ddata.map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply((lambda row: myfunc(*row)), axis=1)).compute(get=get)
```

Full [gist](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/drive/1CMwX6KzRukzL28xUH0xnrdxpBbHdECft#scrollTo=_9EviFJHpliE) is here.

You can also do it the classical way with native Python :

```
import multiprocessing as mp

with mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count()) as pool:
    df['newcol'] = pool.map(f, df['col'])
```